# Reaction of Diazonium salt with Grignard reagent?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

Why doesn't Grignard Reagent undergo Nucleophilic Substitution with a Diazonium Salt? for example if we want to convert phenol to p-cresol. Then first nitrating it, then convert it to a diazonium salt and treating with a methyl grignard reagent. But the reaction dos not happen. Instead we have to use Gilmann Reagent for this process. Why?

Comment: Phenolic group reacts with Grignard's reagent.

Comment: @Mithoron I'm asking about a Diazonium Salt. Also a Phenol with Grignard Reagent gives us phenoxide which is not my objective.

Comment: Well it's like you answered yourself - you have acidic -OH group all the time.

Comment: ok I got it @Mithoron . You are saying that the Grignard Reagent will react with the phenolic group

Comment: This explains the reactivity of Grignards in more detail: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/3959/why-do-organolithium-or-grignard-reagents-act-as-nucleophiles-and-not-as-bases-w